# googletest SetUpTestSuite() does not run

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

From : https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite . I am using 1.11 googletest version.

I am trying to utilize this feature in the following tests:
Game_test.h

```
    class Game_test : public :: testing :: Test
{
protected:
    Game_test() = default;
    virtual ~Game_test() = default;

public:
    void SetUpTestCase()
    {
        Field field(8, 8);
        Engine engine;
        Rules rules;
        GameLogic glogic(&engine, &rules, &field);
    }
};
```

cpp : I expected that it will automatically run SetUpTestCase() for each TEST_F, but it does not. What I am missing?

```
TEST_F(Game_test, apply_rule)
{   
    field.setStatus(1, 2, true); // use of undeclared identifier.....

}
```

P.S. initially I used SetUpTestSuite(), later I tried SetUpTestCase(), which is in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

1. The example is `SetUpTestSuite`, not `SetUpTestCase`.
2. `SetUpTestSuite` should be a static member.
3. `field` should be a static member of the class if used in `SetUpTestSuite`.
4. `SetUpTestSuite` runs once per test suite, not once per test case.
5. If you want something to run once per test case, use `SetUp`, which is a non-static member function.
6. `SetUp` can then manipulate non-static member variables.

See this example that shows the usage of both functions:

```cpp
class Game_test : public testing::Test {
 protected:
  Game_test() = default;
  virtual ~Game_test() = default;

 public:
  static void SetUpTestSuite() {
    std::cout << "========Beginning of a test suit ========" << std::endl;
    static_field = std::string("AAAA");
  }

  void SetUp() override {
    std::cout << "========Beginning of a test ========" << std::endl;
    object_field = std::string("AAAA");
  }

  static std::string static_field;
  std::string object_field;
};

std::string Game_test::static_field;

TEST_F(Game_test, Test1) {
  EXPECT_EQ(static_field, std::string("AAAA"));
  EXPECT_EQ(object_field, std::string("AAAA"));

  // We change object_field, SetUpTestSuite cannot reset it back to "AAAA" because
  // it only runs once at the beginning of the test suite.
  static_field = std::string("BBBB");

  // Although we change object_field here, 
  // SetUp will reset it back to "AAAA" at the beginning of each test case.
  object_field = std::string("BBBB");
}

TEST_F(Game_test, Test2) {
  EXPECT_EQ(static_field, std::string("BBBB"));
  EXPECT_EQ(object_field, std::string("AAAA"));
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/e6Tz1xMr1